# Dynamic query sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, text-files

I have a list of account names in `listnames.txt`

listnames.txt

```
James
Joey
Pete
```

I want to query those list of names in table account Using SQLPLUS the listnames.txt if keep on changing in sqlplus can do loop reading `listname.txt`?

Account table

```
1|Mike
2|James
3|Harris
4|Joey
5|Carl
6|Pete
```

Thanks
jigo

Answer (score 0):

Its better you create a **external table** and based on that data, loop through your lookup table.

With external table you dont load data into db. it just creates a metadata structure of the file. so even if you file changes you can read the changed data directly from the file with a simple select, no need to load again and again.